# In LEGO: How to build a revolving magazine rack for 2x3 tiles?

Tags: building, design, moc, snot, connections

I've been trying for months to come up with a design or parts for a 4-sided spinning magazine rack, like the old wire-style you would see in book stores.  I need it to be fairly stable so I can put in/pull out 2x3 tiles [printed with magazine covers.]  The problem I'm having is the racks are so minimalist that i can't find the sweet spot between form & function.  Bonus points if the rack rotates, but not necessary.

[image: Magazine rack]

I humbly bow down to those who can design such a rack and shower them with good karma (e.g., not finding bricks in the dark with your feet.)

A thousand thanks for your ideas or designs!

***UPDATE***:  Apologies for delays, I've got a lot going on, my LEGO are in storage and it's taken me days to find piece info on Brickset.  (I'm not very familiar with piece names.)
Here are some additional pieces I've tried, along with some clarifications...

**The post of the magazine rack** - this part seems simple enough: a flat tile with a technic pin and a series of other pins and bushings, with the option to stack in the actual rack building pieces.  Hopefully no images are required for this part.

**The individual [magazine] racks** - this is where I struggle.  My thought is some bar-type items, though I have tried other things like 1x2 plates with clips.  I *think* the racks/magazine holding parts probably need to be connected to the post at the top and bottom of each rack for stability, but a simpler design may work.  Some of the pieces I've tried for building the rack and it's connection point(s) to the post include:

= 2566: ASSEMBLY ELEMENT Ø3.2

[image]

= 4733: Brick 1x1 w/ 4 knobs

[image]

= 40244: TUBE 1 M Ø4.85 W. (rotated 90 degrees: pin hole for post, clips for racks)

[image]

= 98397: HANDLEBAR W/3.2

[image]

= 243226: CLAMP 1X2

[image]

= 2540: PLATE 1X2 W. STICK

[image]

= 48336: PLATE 1X2 W. STICK 3.18

[image]

= 4623: PLATE W. HOOK 1X2

[image]

= 3839: MINI HANDLE

[image]

= 53989: BAD ROBOT ARM

[image]

= 30377: SPACE SKELETON ARM

[image]

= 30374: LIGHT SWORD -

[image]

Again, a truly sincere thanks for anyone who can come up with a design.  This magazine rack will be part of a tributary diorama for a dear, dear friend.  Thank you for your considerations.

Here are two more parts I've tried or considered using...

= 98284: LegoPlate, Round 2 x 2 with Pin Hole and 4 Arms Up
[image]

= 48723: LegoTechnic, Axle Connector Hub with 4 Bars and Pin Hole
[image]

...and also this, thinking it would be better for two attachment points, but with no success...

= 35366: [Part 35366] Bar 2 1/4 x 5 1/4 Double Squares (BrickHeadz Glasses Square)  [image]

Comment: How many tiles (newspapers) would you want to fit, would around 12 be enough?

Comment: Can you share your attempts? This would help understanding the scale you are working on and options you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the replies & inquiries!  I think 3 tiers high/12 "magazines" total would be ideal.  I have mostly been trying to work with "bar" items for the racking (think - Handlebar/98397; 1x2 clamp/2432;  plate 1x2 w/ stick/2540; plate 1x2 w/ stick 3.18/48336;  plate w/ hook 1x2/4623;  mini handle/3839, etc.)  I've also tried using robot arms(e.g. 53989), space skeleton arms (e.g.30377) & standalone bars/rods. For the support rod, I figured something Technic [pin-]based, including some frictionless pin sleeves w/ 4 clips (can't find part #.) I'm new to MOCS, so I assume it's my ignorance.

Comment: More specifically to Alex; sorry, I disassembled all failed attempts.  I'm trying to come up with more pieces I tried, but I'm [hopefully!] getting ready to move and all my LEGO are in storage.  My rack won't really be accurately scaled to minifig size because the smallest usable "magazine" size there is [for me] is a 2x3 tile.  1x2 tile's dimensions are not proportionate nor allow more detailed magazine images.  I imagine the rack to be 2-3 racks/"shelves" high.  I've been trying to find some more of the parts I tried on Brickset, so I will post again when I find them.

Comment: Following an update I suggest ditching Brickset parts catalog and use Bricklink or Rebrickable instead. Those two are easier to use and have so much more details.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, Alex.  Will do!

Comment: My apologies for any late gratitude for folks who took the time to reply & validate. I've gotten several bits of hard-to-swallow news lately & my focus has been poor. A truly heartfelt THANKS to those who've proposed suggestions! I really appreciate your creativity & the sacrifice of your time. Your ideas have been great! I was hoping to keep the design down to a single pole & was excited to find parts 2566, 98397, 98284 & 48723.  Not sure if there are more practical parts. How can I show my gratitude to IvanSanchez & Chronocidal? Can I share points or help with your Q's?  I'm good w/ Excel.

Comment: @LEGOSam Contributors on SE usually volunteer their time and expertise because they like helping others, and not for any services in return. However, your expression of gratitude certainly is welcome, additionally you can upvote their answers to grant them Imaginary Internet Points (aka. reputation). You can (and should) accept any answer that has helped you the most by clicking on the checkmark icon on the left side, as outlined in the [tour] and in detail in the [help]. Hope that helped, happy building!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna suggest a different, non-conventional approach. This revolves around offsetting some [6016 3x4 grille](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6016), so each 2x3 tile fits through several grilles at once:

[image]

For an even more minimalistic look, rely on [4733 1x1 brick with studs on 4 sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4733) and [2555 1x1 tile with clip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555), then add your own 1x1 brick/plate column:

[image]

Given the difficulties of making this kind of build look both minimalist and functional, I'm gonna suggest something that some people might see as a heresy: mod your bricks by cutting them. Cut the bottom-most grille so that only one slot (instead of three) remains, and cut the next-to-bottom-most grille so that only two slots remain.

In other words: in the following image, cut by the red line.

[image]

[Beware of some safety precautions and advice when cutting plastic](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/178370-a-question-regarding-customizing-parts). Do wear safety goggles.

To prevent the 2x3 tiles from slipping through too far, consider blocking the slot nearest to the column with a disembodied [983 minifig hand](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=983) (available in black):

[image]

Comment: Ivan, you are amazing (heresy aside, of course. ;-D)  Totally out of the box thinking here, to my mind, and a great inspiration.  Can't tell you how much I appreciate your time and wisdom.  I can't start my build until the summer, but I will try to remember to share my final results in this thread.  Bless you, Ivan, you are the wonderful.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest using [4175 1x2 plate with ladder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4175) together with [3839 1x2 plate with handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3839) SNOTted together with the help of [4070 1x1 brick with headlight](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070), one 2x2 plate and 2 1x2 plates, like so:

[image]

Yes, the whole thing is upside-down. This is normal.

This contraption will hold the 2x3 tile snugly, thanks to the offset provided by the lip of the headlight brick. The handle plate will prevent the tile from sliding to the sides while allowing the tile to wiggle a bit. This can be seen in this top view:

[image]

Build a few of those, and place them on top of each other in a ladder-like manner, like so:

[image]

Add an upside-down 2x6 plate with a [3937 1x2 hinge brick base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937) plus [3938 1x2 hinge brick top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938), so the entire structure *hangs*, like so:

[image]

...add a column to the center of the 2x6 plate, and the rest is pretty much symmetrical. It might be possible to attach extra hinged plates at the base of the structure for extra stability.

Unfortunately, this design is somewhat bulky. I cannot think (right now) of any other slanted-SNOT design that is more compact. On the plus side, this slanted design offers perfect functionality when getting tiles in/out of the racks.

If you want more than one 2x3 tile per rack, or a looser fit, try getting rid of the headlight bricks, rotating the handle plates 90°.

---

EDIT: I've been fiddling a bit with your suggestions of [98397 Utensil handlebars](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98397) and space skeleton arm... just to remember about the existence of other arm pieces like [93061 Arm Skeleton, Bent with Clips at 90 degrees](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93061). Together with some [85861 1x1 plate round with open stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93061), [63965 Bar 6L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63965) and [4032 2x2 plate round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4032), it's possible to do something like:

[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure if the bent skeleton arms will have enough grip. If they do not, some of the handlebar pieces might drop, and individual racks might rotate out of place.

Note that I'm using four bars there - using one bar doesn't provide enough room, and the individual racks would collide with each other. Hence the 1x1 round hollow plates.

Comment: Would your last design (with the handlebars) work with [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48723&name=Technic,%20Axle%20Connector%20Hub%20with%204%20Bars%20and%20Pin%20Hole&category=%5BTechnic,%20Connector%5D#T=C) and [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98313#T=C), for a little extra support?

Comment: With a 8L or 10L axle? I guess it would work, but after fiddling with LeoCAD to make a prototype, I think that design has a flaw: the 2x3 tiles would slide towards the central axle and clash with each other. Right now I'm wondering towards [30033 2x2 plate with octagonal frame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30033) AKA [75937](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=75937), plus 2 clips via 1x1 plates e.g. [4085](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4085).

Comment: Thanks again, Ivan. I very genuinely appreciate your efforts & time. Your 2nd design is much closer to what I was looking for. I've been reluctant to recognize your answer just yet for fear that it would end the discussion, but you definitely deserve props so I have liked your answer.  Hopefully that won't close the topic, but I didn't want to wait any longer to [tangibly] recognize your efforts and ideas.  If I can figure out how to put a bounty up, I may try to do that, too.  Thanks to ALL for their support with ideas AND suggestions for how to better help & interact with the community.

Comment: You're welcome, @LEGOSam ;-) BTW do try a design with 30033.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try 4 copies of [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle on Side with Free Ends](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2540), for the "base" of each level, with [Flag 2 x 2 Square](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2335) as the "rack"?, and 2x2 bricks (square or round) up the centre?  Then stick the whole thing on a 2x2 turntable base.

Depending on clutch strength, you might need another part on the diagonals, to stop the flags from opening out too wide.

Comment: Thanks, Chronocidal!  The design isn't exactly "it", but I do like the possible idea of using flags.  Many thanks for your time, considerations, and suggestion!